# Variable height div on top of a fixed height div

Tags: html, css

I would like to create the following layout using only css and html if possible:

```
 __________________________________
|   ____________________________   |
|  |                            |  |
|  |   div1  variable height    |  |
|  |                            |  |
|  |                            |  |
|  |                            |  |
|  |                            |  |
|   ----------------------------   |
|   ____________________________   |
|  |                            |  |
|  |     div2   (50px height)   |  |
|   ----------------------------   |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  | 
|                                  |
 ---------------------------------
```

div1 has variable height and should expand as the content grows , and if there is no more space a vertical scroll bar should appear.

div2 shoud stay under div1 all the time

I tried like this

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="div1">div1
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content
        <br>content</div>
    <div id="div2">div2</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#div1 {
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:green;
}
#div2 {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/xucqF/16/

The problem here is that if the viewport is not big enough to fit all the content, the scrollbar appears at the whole body instead of div1 itself.

Comment: FYI - your fiddle doesnt resemble the code in the question...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited my question, now the fiddle link is the right one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the code in your question, you can use the below CSS.

By using `calc` to calculate the `max-height` of the content `div`, you can achieve the behaviour you're after.

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xucqF/19/)

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#div1 {
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:green;
    max-height:calc(100% - 50px);
}
#div2 {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;   
}
```

Comment: The first div should expand only to fit it's content and not further.

Comment: @IstvánGeréb - please see http://jsfiddle.net/xucqF/19/ (same as above), this is the case?

Comment: Yes this is the exact case. The only problem is that I would accomplish this without the calc function. calc is not supported by older browsers.

Comment: @IstvánGeréb - I'm afraid calc is the only way

Comment: I was afraid that this is going to be the answer. Thank you anyway for the fast reply :)